# Conversion of timespec for Windows 7 VS 2010

Tags: c++, build, time.h

I am trying to build OpenVDB viewer for Windows 7 and bumped into this line of code:

```
secs = fabs(secs);
int isecs = int(secs);
struct timespec sleepTime = { isecs /*sec*/, int(1.0e9 * (secs - isecs)) /*nsec*/ };
nanosleep(&sleepTime, /*remainingTime=*/NULL);
```

Unfortunately, i dont know what exactly is the meaning of this code as i need to make it VS2010 compiler compatible in order to build it.
So, can i know what is the equivalent of this code or some other library that i can use to edit it easily??

Comment: If you can live with milliseconds resolution at ~10ms precision, simply use Win32 function ''Sleep(mysleeptimeinmilliseconds)'' to replace all that unix gibberish ;)

Comment: @user2225104, i have searched for similar function that could replace it, but the problem is that i didnt actually understand the code, not really good at this kind of thing, thanks btw.

Comment: The purpose of the code you posted is to suspend the execution of the current thread for a certain amount of time.

Comment: @user2225104, ok, trying now to read through the examples of timespec, can you suggest most suitable library for this that is included in vs2010, maybe i will try to translate it. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming `secs` is a float value giving the time the thread shall sleep in seconds, such as e.g.

```
float secs = 0.8312f;
```

You can replace that for the windows version with:

```
float secs = 0.8312f;
DWORD delay = static_cast<DWORD>(fabs(secs * 1000.0f));
Sleep(delay);
```

Possibly you could add some checks to this (such as if secs is not negative...).

In order to keep the main code base portable, you could create an extra module where you define your own portable sleep function, maybe with the signature `void PortableSleep(float seconds);`.  Then, place in one .cpp file the Unix implementation, in another the win32 implementation and link accordingly.

What you also can do is using `std::this_thread::sleep_for()` if you like to waste time on figuring out how the `<chrono>` stuff works (VS lacks one feature, which makes it a bit harder to use).

Comment: Thanks a lot. Will try it later. Appreciates your help, cheers.